# WEBDAV xml to object/json in PHP?

Tags: php, webdav, owncloud, simplexml

I've got webdav PROPFIND xml response that I'm getting from OwnCloud.  I need to convert to a PHP object (and ultimately json).  The problem is that the response is heavy with namespaces, which php's simplexml apparently can't handle very well.

This is what the xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
<d:response>
 <d:href>/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/ownCloudUserManual.pdf</d:href>
 <d:propstat>
   <d:prop>
     <d:getlastmodified>Sun, 04 Oct 2015 18:01:18 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
     <d:getcontentlength>2241884</d:getcontentlength>
     <d:resourcetype/>
     <d:getetag>"b00009ac4b1b17c45667abd2a6d2f7c7"</d:getetag>
     <d:getcontenttype>application/pdf</d:getcontenttype>
   </d:prop>
   <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
 </d:propstat>
</d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

When I put it through simplexml, I do not get anything back:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
  print_r( $xml );
```

The print_r gives:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
{}
```

There doesn't appear to be any simplexml errors (as returned from libxml_get_errors()) - there's just nothing returned but an empty class.

I could use some advice on how to parse the XML into *something* useful.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Dumping the simplexml object doesn't yield anything, but that does not imply that it wasn't parsed properly. You can still access the properties as you normally do. XPath is highly recommended.

Comment: SimpleXML has no problem with namespaces; it does, however, have a problem with `print_r`. Search for "SimpleXML namespaces" and you'll get lots of existing answers on this. Hint: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Comment: @cardinalPilot Which approach did you end up with? Did you manage to get some kind of json wrapper around the WebDAV API?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and found out how to solve this. The comments above point in the right direction, but I wanted to show an actual solution here:

you need to get the namespaces that are inferred in the second line of the XML code with "xmlns:..":

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
```

Then you can pick all children of the desired namespace ('d') with the following command:

```
$child = $xml->children($ns['d']);
```

after that, you can iterate the 'response' elements and extract information from their children:

```
foreach ($child->response as $files) {
    echo $files->href . "<br>";
}
```

that will output for example all the HREF elements, in your case the "/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/ownCloudUserManual.pdf" and any other directory contents.